# Custom model in Apache Open NLP

Tags: apache, opennlp

I am working currently with custom models which I am training for my own use case. My use case is to classify emails based on whether it is an address change request. If the address change request could be understood from a single sentence, it is working fine without issues. But if the address change request needs to be understood from multiple sentences, it is not working. 
Giving few examples below :-
Example 1 :- THIS IS WORKING
1. 
a)training file :-

```
Guys I wish to <START:contactupdate> change my address <END> .
```

My new address is 68 Dorset Road, Coventry, West Midlands, CV1 4ED.
Please confirm once you are done.
Thanks.

b)Testing model with the below sentence :-
String input = "Guys I wish to change my address.My new address is 68 Dorset Road, Coventry, West Midlands, CV1 4ED.Please confirm once you are done. Thanks."; //Working

2. EXAMPLE 2 :- This is not working.
   Lets say the address change request can only be deduced from multiple lines.

   "My old address is no longer valid. Need to update it."

How do I train my model in this scenario?How do I specify the custom tags for above?

Can you please help. I am stuck.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with not working? That the thing you want to retrieve is not retrieved? Or that the training crashes somewhere when the tags are spread out over multiple lines?

In general, the (by default MaxEnt) model that you are training in this procedure tries to detect common features for the thing you are training for. Typically, these are named entities like persons, organisations, locations. And in many languages, these contain typical features (like the prefix Mr./Mrs., the suffix corp., the morpheme "street", respectively). This can be picked up by the model, and applied in new data, leading to the recognition of whichever it is you want to recognise. The thing you are trying to do however, is pretty advanced NLP already. Since the longer the phrase, the larger the possible variation, it becomes more difficult to pick up commonalities. I'd say for your use case, people are typically using parsing (either constituency or dependency parsing) or other more sophisticated tools than just this relatively flat pattern recognition. So you may want to look into these instead. I don't know how much data you have at your disposal, from which you can infer different ways of expressing the desire to change an address in a customer database. If reasonable (i.e. not just a couple of sentences), you may want to manually annotate them, parse the corpus, use machine learning on the parse trees/graphs for the sentences of interest and go about it in this way. As mentioned, quite  advanced NLP in my opinion, and not something that has an out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are trying to categorize emails to find out if its for address change. But the model example looks like for named entity. In my opinion, it might be better to use "Document Categorizer" feature of Apache OpenNLP.

You can provide different samples for possible sentences which can be categorized as address change. "Address_change", "general_inquiry" etc. can be a categories. This way you can add as many different sampels as you want with many variations of sentences. Here is [easy & basic tutorial for document categorization training & usage.](http://itsallbinary.com/natural-language-processing-in-java-using-apache-opennlp-document-categorizer-simple-example-for-beginners/)